# Will Hive calculate a aggregation twice in one select?

Tags: hive, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I know that an Hive SQL query like this:

```
SELECT users, users > 0 AS have_user
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(user) AS users
  FROM sometable
  GROUP BY something
);
```

will create a single map reduce job, which is nice. However, I want to avoid too many subqueries in my code. For example:

```
SELECT SUM(user) AS user, SUM(user) > 0 AS have_user
FROM sometable
GROUP BY something;
```

In the above code, will Hive calculate this SUM aggregation once or twice?

Comment: Why don't you just run an `EXPLAIN` command and check the execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive will not perform 2 different jobs with map/reduce phases or calculate the aggregation twice, it will do it only one. You can take a look to the execution plan like this

```
explain
SELECT users, users > 0 AS have_user
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(user) AS users
  FROM sometable
  GROUP BY something
);
```

you should be able to see only 1 aggregation like this

```
Group By Operator
  aggregations: sum(VALUE._col0)
```

it will reuse the aggregation result for your select condition

```
  Select Operator
    expressions: _col1 (type: bigint), (_col1 > 0) (type: boolean)
    outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `hive` will interpret that query, but i would correct your query with `HAVING` clause :

Here is a correct version of Query :

```
SELECT something, SUM(user) AS have_user, 
FROM table 
GROUP BY something
HVAING SUM(user) > 0;
```

Comment: IMHO that's a different query. The original does not make any sense, but does not filter out "anonymous" counts of zero. Your query does.